# want to implement authentication on cassandra cluster which is in produciton

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am new to cassandra and I have a cassandra(3.5) cluster which is running without authentication, now i want to implement authentication on the running cluster by taking aws AMI's, and i set up 4 new instances, if i start the cassandra in new instances it created lot of trouble, it was mixed with the old cluster because of same cluster name and token values and i have tried to change the cluster name but if i did that then the whole cluster might get effect. Please guide me how to implement authentication on the cluster without any trouble.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: could you provide cassandra.yaml and cluster description ? How much nodes are in the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about jmx authentication then edit ***install_location/conf/jmxremote.password***. Add one line to the bottom-

`cassandra cassandra`

Here first 'cassandra' will represent user and the second 'cassandra' will represent password. So that when you'll want to see the nodetool status, you need to enter the command-

`nodetool -u cassandra -pw cassandra status`

for `cqlsh` authentication, you can follow this link - https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/security_config_native_authenticate_t.html